# Wrong when using split in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I use split in Java like this

```
String str = "Bx=1946^Cx=1043423";
String[] parts = str.split("^");
for (String part : parts)
    System.out.println(part);
```

But it turns out there is only one element in parts array after splitting, so if I want to use "^" as delimiter, what should I write?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't hurt to read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) :3

Comment: I'd highly recommend using the Apache `StringUtils` split methods over the standard java ones, especially seeing as they can use regular String delimiters without the potential added confusion of regex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to escape the`^`, which has a special meaning in regex (start of word, line and others):

```
String str = "Bx=1946^Cx=1043423";
String[] parts = str.split("\\^");
for (String part : parts)
    System.out.println(part);
```

The output will be:

```
Bx=1946
Cx=1043423
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
str.split(Pattern.quote("^"));
```

instead of

```
str.split("^");
```

`Pattern.quote()` works in case of splitting with multiple symbols too. For example, we can use `str.split(Pattern.quote("^^^^"));` instead of adding too many special characters like `str.split("\\^\\^\\^\\^")`.

Comment: Why do you claim this is a better answer than the accepted answer?

Comment: `Pattern.quote()` works in case of splitting with multiple symbols too. eg: 
we can use `str.split(Pattern.quote("^^^^"));` instead of adding too many special characters like `str.split("\\^\\^\\^\\^")`

Comment: @TheThom why not? It does *answer* the question.

Comment: @MarounMaroun It does now. Thanks for the explanation.